# Azure AD B2C translation of custom HTML elements

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure AD B2C custom UI and I'm wondering if it is possible to use the translation of own HTML elements

Here is an example:

```html
<hr />
<h3 class="text-center" id="Custom1SignUpNewAccountMessage>Sign up with a new account</h3>
<div id="api" data-name="SelfAsserted">
</div>
```

I can see the text "*Sign up with a new account*". Now I would like to translate it for different languages because at the moment it is fixed.

I used the JSON from DefaultLocalizedResources.

```
"LocalizedStrings": [
{
   "ElementType": "UxElement",
   "ElementId": null,
   "StringId": "Custom1SignUpNewAccountMessage",
   "Override": true,
   "Value": "Hier neuen Acount registrieren!!!"
 },
```

Unfortunately, `Custom1SignUpNewAccountMessage` is not a valid element.

Is it possible to do translation "outside" `<div id="api" ...>`?

Answer (score 2):

The B2C multi-language string overrides are only for the translation of strings that are rendered by B2C. That's the feature's primary purpose because otherwise there is no easy way for developers to translate these strings as they do not have direct control over them.

B2C does not provide a framework for translation of strings not rendered by it. That will need to be handled by the application, and typically there are existing developer frameworks that can be used by developers depending on the platform of their choice.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. Is there any chance to do this via a "custom attribute"? Seems there are only 3 data types (string,int,bool). Seems I can only add an attribute the user needs to fill in data. It would be cool if I could add "readonly text".

Is there any other chance to put in the DIV a custom attribute/text which is localized?